# Finding the probability using probability distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A contractor is required by a county planning department to submit 1-5 forms in applying for a building permit. Let $Y$ be the number of forms required of the next applicant. The probability that $y$ forms are required is known to be proportional to $y$, that is $p(y)=ky$ for $y=1,2,3,4,5$.

What is the probability that at most three forms are required?

So I have determined that $k=\dfrac{1}{15}$, I have found multiple solutions to this problem saying to simply add up $P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)+P(Y=3)$ which gives $\dfrac{2}{5}$.

My attempt at the problem was to invert "at most three forms are required" to "at least 2 forms are required" and find the probability using $1-P(\text{at least }2 \text { forms are required})$. I found that $P(\text{at least }2 \text { forms are required})=P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)$ , $P(Y=1)=\dfrac{1}{15}$ and $P(Y=2)=\dfrac{2}{15}$. So the probability that at most three forms is equal to $1-(\dfrac{1}{15}+\dfrac{2}{15})=\dfrac{4}{5}$. Did I do something wrong? Shouldn't this give me the same probability if I inverted the condition? If this method does not work for this problem, could someone explain why?

Comment: The complement of "at most three forms are required" is not "at least 2 forms are required" and [at least 2 forms are required] is not [Y=1]$\cup$[Y=2].

Comment: I found my mistake, the complement of "at most three forms are required" is "a least 4 forms are required" and that is $[Y=4]\cup [Y=5]$ which gives me the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed. You may post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of "at most three forms are required" is not :at least 2 forms are required" but "at least four forms are required". $P(Y\ge 4)=P(Y=4)+P(Y=5)$. The probability that "at most three forms are required" is equal to $1-P(Y \ge4)$. Using this will get the correct answer $\dfrac{2}{5}$.